# Jar execution command error from first line

Tags: java, jar, weka

From [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) repository

I try to execute the command.

```
./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
```

However I receive this error.

```
C:/weka/weka-3-4/weka.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
C:/weka/weka-3-4/weka.jar: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:/weka/weka-3-4/weka.jar: line 2: `▒=1 META-INF/▒=1META-INF/MANIFEST.MF▒M▒▒LK-.▒K-*▒▒ϳR0▒3▒▒M▒▒▒u▒I,.▒R(O▒N▒K/▒▒s▒t▒▒▒/N-▒r.JM,IM▒u▒▒Rp▒+▒1▒3▒▒P▒׀NMPK'
./PersonalityRecognizer: line 15: : command not found
```

I have download weka jar file and give the path in the following file as requested by the instructions:

```
#! /bin/bash -

# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

JDK_PATH=../../apps/jdk1.5.0_05
WEKA=../../apps/weka-3-4/weka.jar

# ----------------------------------

COMMONS_CLI=./lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar
MRC=./lib/jmrc.jar

LIBS=.:$WEKA:$COMMONS_CLI:$MRC:bin/

$JDK_PATH/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath $LIBS recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer $*
```

Comment: Are you using windows or *nix based OS?

Comment: @jhenrique `C:/weka/weka-3-4/weka.jar` would imply windows

Comment: Then you can try to run ./PersonalityRecognizer.bat

Comment: I didn't find the ./PersonalityRecognizer script (.bat, .py or .sh) file anywhere in the repo

Comment: @Woodsman the batch and bash script is not in the repo, but it can be downloaded from a link in the github repo's documentation (http://farm2.user.srcf.net/research/personality/recognizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jhenrique said, if you use windows you have to edit the PersonalityRecognizer.bat (you seem to have edited the bash script but ran on windows).

Then you have to make sure the directory structure looks like this:

```
  \ Personality-Recognition-in-SD-master (this is the cloned repo's root)
    +---apps
    +---Classification
    +---data
    +---mrc
    +---output_dir
    \---PersonalityRecognizer (this contains the PersonalityRecognizer.bat and bash scripts, note the subdirectory)
```

You also have to make sure you edit the **PersonalityRecognizer.properties** in PersonalityRecognizer subdir, to include your application path. If you use windows you have to use double / for path separator:

```
##################################################
# Configuration File of the Personality Recognizer
##################################################

# All variables should be modified according to your
# directory structure

# Warning: for Windows paths, backslashes need to be
# doubled, e.g. c:\\Program Files\\Recognizer

# Root directory of the application
appDir = F:\\Personality-Recognition-in-SD-master\\PersonalityRecognizer

# Path to the LIWC dictionary file (LIWC.CAT)
liwcCatFile = lib/LIWC.CAT

# Path to the MRC Psycholinguistic Database file (mrc2.dct)
mrcPath = ../mrc/mrc2.dct
```

**Update:**
Also make sure, that the JDK_PATH and WEKA variables in the PersonalityRecognizer.bat point to a valid JDK path and WEKA path (weka.jar is contained in the repo you cloned):

```
@echo off
rem WINDOWS LAUNCH SCRIPT

rem ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES TO MODIFY

set JDK_PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01"
set WEKA="F:\Personality-Recognition-in-SD-master\apps\weka-3-4\weka.jar"

rem ----------------------------------

set COMMONS_CLI="lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar"
set JMRC="lib\jmrc.jar"

set LIBS=%WEKA%;%COMMONS_CLI%;%JMRC%;%CD%;bin\

%JDK_PATH%\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath %LIBS% recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Comment: Thank you. Please do you have any idea for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348586/find-the-right-way-to-produce-a-fine ?