# Find the right way to produce a fine

Tags: python, json

I try to configure locally [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD) repository

When I tried to execute this command `python feature_extraction.py -t 1 [-nlon] -i mairesse_Apache.arff` I understood that there is a need for one more fine named results

Here is my mailcorpus.json file I user for my test:

```
[
   {
      "id":12,
      "mailing_list_url":"12",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"test@test.org",
      "message_body":"Here is one text to test sentiment and feel happy",
      "is_response_of":"before"
   },
   {
      "id":21,
      "mailing_list_url":"21",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"test@gmail.com",
      "message_body":"Here is one text to test sentiment and feel happy and feel fine",
      "is_response_of":"before"
   },
   {
      "id":21,
      "mailing_list_url":"23",
      "type_of_recipient":"From",
      "email_address":"23@gmail.com",
      "message_body":"Not feel so good for this code",
      "is_response_of":"after"
   }
]
```

There is an example named skeleton in the repository and has this structure

```
[
    {
        "id_test": "uid",
        "time": "mm:ss",
        "email": "email@ddress\t",
        "extraversion": 1.0,
        "coscientiousness": 2.0,
        "agreeableness": 3.0,
        "openness": 4.0,
        "neuroticism": 5.0
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there any idea how can I receive this results file for my mailcorpus.json file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  AN off-site link is not acceptable; such things are volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository provided in your link doesn't seem to be intended for public consumption.  The file example you list is not in fact an output but an input (and there is no code in the repository to dump json).  I don't expect you to be able to run the code at all.

```
In the data/ folder, you will also find:

the training_data.rda model from the NLoN R package;
the skeleton of the json that will contain the responses from the mini-IPIP test taken by your subjects.
```

You would presumably need to administer the mini-IPIP test yourself in this case.

Comment: But how it is possible?

Comment: You may be able to get some data from step 2 of `Pipeline (Apache)` - see the link to http://farm2.user.srcf.net/research/personality/recognizer